# ITMS-90473: CFBundleVersion Mismatch

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, fastlane

This is quite interesting case. I have **main app** and **share extension**. To distribute it I use **fastlane** tool. So far everything was ok. But recently I had to change one setting (requirement from 3rd party library to make it working properly) in fastlane.

1. This is my function I use in fastlane:

   ```
   def archive(options)
       prepare_for_archive(options)
       build_ios_app(
           workspace: WORKSPACE,
           scheme: options[:scheme],
           clean: true,
           export_method: options[:adhoc] ? "ad-hoc" : "app-store",
           export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
           output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH,
           export_options:{ manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber: false }, //❗️here is the thing I had to add recently to make 3rd library working properly.
       )
   end
   ```

Inside `prepare_for_archive`

```
  build_number = PIPELINE || "1"

  set_info_plist_value(
    path: INFO_PLIST_PATH,
    key: "CFBundleVersion",
    value: build_number
  )

  set_info_plist_value(
    path: SHARE_INFO_PLIST_PATH,
    key: "CFBundleVersion",
    value: build_number
  )
```

where `PIPELINE` is defined as `PIPELINE = ENV["CI_PIPELINE_ID"]`

Documentation why I had to do it is [Autopay SDK - If you build your project by Xcode 13 or newer](https://developer.autopay.pl/autopay-sdk/dokumentacja/ios/project-preparation#if-you-build-your-project-by-xcode-13-or-newer)

and then I started receiving the following mails:

> App Store Connect
>
> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "APP" 1.41.0 (13204). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90473: CFBundleVersion Mismatch - The CFBundleVersion value '1' of extension 'APP.app/PlugIns/APP_Share.appex' does not match the CFBundleVersion value '13204' of its containing iOS application 'APP.app'.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I have replaced the app name with `APP`.

Everything was fine with versions and numbers before that change. Is there anything I can do with it to keep Autopay working and keep the build numbers (actually) consistent?

Comment: I think this should be resolved by AutoPay. They should find an isolated way of managing their version numbers.